# Rails units testing: No route matches why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm trying to do some units test, this is my first time.

I don't really understand why there is `No route matches`.

When i run `$ rake test test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb`

i get this in the output of the console:

```
1) Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_get_edit:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"products"}
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'


  2) Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_get_show:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products"}
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:35:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'


  3) Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_get_create:
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: product
    app/controllers/products_controller.rb:59:in 'product_params'
    app/controllers/products_controller.rb:18:in 'create'
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'


  4) Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_get_update:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"products"}
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'


  5) Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_get_destroy:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"products"}
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:30:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'

7 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 5 errors, 0 skips
```

---

This is the products_controller_test.rb file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get create" do
    get :create
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get update" do
    get :update
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get destroy" do
    get :destroy
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get show" do
    get :show
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

---

routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :products
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For all these routes (edit, update, destroy), you need to say *which* product you're editing/updating/destroying. If Rails doesn't know it, it can't draw the route for you.

For edit, for example, the full route would be `products/:product_id/edit`. So Rails will need to 'fill in' the :product_id key. If you leave it blank the route breaks.

In your code, then, if you're calling `get :edit`, you need to specify a product id. Like so:

`get :edit, product_id: products(:test_product).id`

(using the fixtures explained in the Rails test tutorial [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html))